# Socket being busy causes delays in poll()

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I'm using a TCP socket to send data from a client.  The data is prepared, in advance, so I always have more data to send.  Moreover, I can't change the size of the writes, otherwise the server will complain.  I do the following:

```
while (1) {
    poll(for POLLOUT condition);
    write(to TCP socket);
    if (no more data)
        break;
}
```

The problem is that the POLL takes a very long time.  I assume this is the time that the socket is actually being written to (or responded to).  Is there anyway that I can reduce the amount of time spent in the poll?  It is currently a major bottleneck.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the data passed to write arrives in one unit at the other end, so if your server has opinions you are in for a problem.

Comment: Socket is flushed and Nagle's algorithm is disabled. The server is rather picky about how it receives the data, and that's been accounted for.

Comment: What's the bandwith for the client? I'm pretty sure that's the bottleneck. If not, you haven't told us the whole story...

Comment: You can pretty much saturate a 1Gbps link with this approach. That is if the other end receives the data fast enough. You should trace the connection with wireshark and 1. Look at the bandwidth you're producing, 2. Figure out if the other end is slow in reading(you'll have to look at the window size and have some knowledge on how TCP operates).

Comment: @wlformyd Disabling the Nagle algorithm etc. may help a bit, but it still won't guarantee that the units read correspond to the units written. Nothing can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Socket being busy causes delays in poll()

Of course it does. That's what `poll()` is for. To delay until a socket becomes readable or writable.

Your writer is faster than your reader. Look for a solution at the reading end. Your writing end is behaving correctly.

However calling it every time at the head of that loop is pointless. Only call it when you need to know the socket has *become* writable. It is normally writable all the time, except when your socket send buffer is full, so calling it every time is a waste of time.

Just keep writing until you get `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK.` *Then* is the time to call `poll()`, to tell you when there is space in the socket send buffer. Then just resume writing again as before.

Answer (score 3):

`Poll` will raise a `POLLOUT` event when there's enough buffer space to enqueue further data. (Look at this link - [Man (7) socket](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/socket.7.html) )

If it doesn't, it means write buffer is full and it means you're writing faster than the read capabilities of the other peer. Or simply the network is slower than you expect.

Comment: Would increasing the send window size help? Or would that just delay the inevitable... I have it set at 1 MB, and the writes are 256K.

Comment: Do you mean write buffer size? Anyway, i think it's inevitable... sorry =(

Comment: check the bandwith with `iperf`.

Comment: @wlformyd Increasing the socket send buffer will help for a short period, *until you fill it*. After that it's exactly the same. It is incorrect to speak of a 'send window size'. There isn't such a thing.